# Cannot understand while reading simplicial=singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was reading http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/MAT1300/Week%2010-12%20Term%202.pdf
, and I can't understand the last paragraph of pg 29, and the first paragraph of pg 30.

It says that "To compute the singular group  $ H_n (X ^ k , X^{k-1} ) $, consider all the simplices together as a map $ \phi : \sqcup _\alpha (\Delta _\alpha ^k , \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k ) \rightarrow (X^k , X^{k-1} ) $", but what does $\sqcup _\alpha (\Delta _\alpha ^k , \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k ) $ means, and what is this map exactly?

At pg 30, it says that "note that it gives a homeomorphism of quotient spaces."
I cannot understand this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build $X^k$ from $X^{k-1}$ you attach a $\Delta_\alpha^k$ by gluing its boundary, $\partial\Delta_\alpha^k$, to $X^{k-1}$.  So, $\sqcup_\alpha(\Delta_\alpha^k,\partial\Delta_\alpha^k)$ is the disjoint union of all the $k$-simplices, making special note of their boundaries.  The $\phi$ is the map that attaches each simplex by identifying its boundary to some part of $X^{k-1}$.

Moreover the homeomorphism part has to do with the fact that $X^k/X^{k-1}$ and $\cup_\alpha\Delta_\alpha^k/\partial\Delta_\alpha^k$ are both a collection of spheres.  The homeomorphism between them is induced by $\phi$.

Comment: @Haullab Didn't see that part at first.  Made an edit.

Comment: um... then for the last part, why is $ H( \Delta _\alpha ^k / \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k ) $ isomorphic to $H(X^k / X^{k-1} )$ ? is it because these are collection of spheres?

Comment: @Haullab A homeomorphism induces an isomorphism on homology.  That's the "invariance of homotopy type" part of homology.  It's not just that they are a collection of wedge sums of spheres.  It's also that there are the same number of spheres in each wedge.

Comment: uh... I'm new to this... I can't understand about if $  \Delta _\alpha ^k /\sqcup _\alpha  \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k  $ is homeomorphic to $ X^k / X^{k-1} $ , then $  \Delta _\alpha ^k / \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k  $ homeomorphic to $X^k / X^{k-1} $.
(Is this statement correct?)

Comment: @Haullab You should have $\cup_\alpha\Delta_\alpha^k/\partial\Delta_\alpha^k$.  Likewise, there should be a union symbol $H_n(\cup_\alpha\Delta_\alpha^k/\partial\Delta_\alpha^k)$.

Comment: @Haullab The paper you are reading should also have the union symbol.

Comment: Oh, so $ H_n ( \Delta _\alpha ^k  / \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k ) $ should be $ H_n ( \sqcup _\alpha \Delta _\alpha ^k  / \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k ) $ ?

Comment: @Haullab Yes.  There is a small technicality.  The $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint union.  But, after you quotient, you end up with a one point union.  So you'd use either $\cup$ or $\vee$.

Comment: So I should read like $ H_n ( \vee (\Delta _ \alpha ^k / \partial \Delta _\alpha ^k ) ) $ ? It makes a lot more sense..

Comment: @Haullab Correct.